# Graph recognition software

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

[ISGCI](http://wwwteo.informatik.uni-rostock.de/isgci/classes.cgi) lists a lot of graph classes, many of which are recognizable in polynomial time. Is anyone here aware of actual implementations of these algorithms?

Comment: This question lists a bunch of graph manipulation packages. Maybe one of them: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26231/is-there-any-complete-graph-theory-package

Comment: If you mean, is there freely available, reasonable quality code, then I believe the answer is no.  As far as I understand, algorithms for some of the ISGCI classes have been implemented, but typically these are rough-and-ready prototypes.